# Making a DSL and an interpreter in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, interpreter, dsl, emf

i have to do a DSL and an interpreter of it using Eclipse modeling framework i think so , because i dont have a lot of information about it . I have four months to do it and i am very lost .

The DSL have to read files from sensors , and with the DSL you can make complex math operations . Anyone one know any free resource/book/tutorial/guide where i can read about that ( i can't find anything useful) or anyone can tell my some clues to follow and how start . Thank you so much.

I try to find some examples doing someting like that and i can't find anything.

Comment: It seems you have missed the most obvious projects for this kind of task: Xtext, Xcore, Xbase...

Comment: yes , i know that with Xtext i can make a DSL but can i implement a interpreter with it? , i dont understand the "workflow" to put together all the tools for make all .

Answer (score 1):

*[Eclipse Modeling Project: A Domain-Specific Language (DSL) Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001XT60YW)* and *[EMF: Eclipse Modeling Framework (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0013TPYVW)* are two great books on this topic that you can get used for about five dollars each. While not free, they are well worth the small price. There is also a newer reference [Implementing Domain Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1786464969) that seems very relevant but I have not had the pleasure of reading it yet, so can't vouch for it.

There are also many free talks on these subjects on youtube and all the EMF, Xtext, etc. websites have quite a bit of tutorials.

Also, based on this question: [Interpreter vs. Code Generator Xtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296582/interpreter-vs-code-generator-xtext?rq=1) , Xtext does not appear to support interpreters but Xbase may.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples of using XText to build an interpreter / interpreted language (eg. https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/202_scripting.html).

For me, it took a while to get all plugins configurations correct, but it is well documented, on Xtext web and in github / tutorials.

Also, look at XTend (http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) as this is a major birck in XText framework.